# date after two weeks from current date in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I do to extract date after two weeks from current date?

Example

```
SELECT blabla
FROM table
WHERE blabla IN [sysdate + 2 weeks]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about ... ?

```
SELECT blabla
  FROM table
 WHERE blabla > SYSDATE AND blabla < SYSDATE +14;
```

This `SYSDATE +x` means `x` days from now on.

**p.s.**: for records with date *now +14* use ...

```
SELECT blabla
  FROM table
 WHERE blabla LIKE SYSDATE +14;
```

**p.p.s.** as Ben pointed out below, there is a potential risk in using `LIKE` as it depends on the `nls_date_format` parameter. Take care that an appropriate format is set or have a look at Gordons approach. @Ben: Thanks for the note.

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

Comment: This returns the period of `blabla` between current date and date after 2 weeks. What I want to do is extract blabla exactly after 2 weeks from current date.

Comment: So you mean you want to select all data from day *now +14 days* ; then you can use `LIKE (SYSDATE +14)`

Comment: Please **never** use `blabla LIKE SYSDATE +14;` @khan. You'll be doing implicit date to character conversion and it can be different in _every_ session.

Comment: @Ben: that depends on the requirements regarding performance; if millions of rows are evaluated or the query is running several thousand times per day - yes, then this approach is not really recommended. In that case Gordons second proposal or - perhaps even better - a function based index (on `TRUNC (blabla)`) is preferable.

Comment: No, this approach is _never_ recommended @Trinimon. It is completely dependent on the NLS_DATE_FORMAT of the session and Oracle's implicit conversion of that to a character. If the NLS_DATE_FORMAT is `Month YY`, for instance, then this approach is completely useless. Oracle [explicitly recommends against relying on implicit conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements002.htm#i53062).

Comment: Well, I assumed `blabla` to be a DATE column (not VARCHAR2), so I don't see any issues regarding functionality here, because both sides get converted the same way. The only potential issue might be low performance.

Comment: If they get converted into something that doesn't have a day you don't see any issues? Or something with the time first? With LIKE you're also assuming that there's no time... if the times are different there'll be no positive matches.

Comment: Please provide an example (using DATEs only) that demonstrates the issue. I've been working with quite some high performance environments and - believe it or not - `LIKE` was occasionally used without any issues. Finally 'yes', I ignored times by intention - as Gordon did by using `TRUNC`.

Comment: You can `@reply` me; I'm not getting notified of your comments. [Here's proof](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1984/2) though... You ignored times by ignoring them, which means you won't get a positive hit when you want one. Gordon actually removed them. The first one was a good example but I lost it. Times change. It originally returned 2 records...

Comment: I'd prefer this example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1984/5; so what we can see here is: one shouldn't use `LIKE` if the `nls_date_format` is set to something that doesn't reflect a pure date. For me that was valid in almost all environments - so I had never any issues using `LIKE`.

Answer (score 3):

When you are doing this, you need to be careful about the time fractions.  If you are not concerned about indexes, then you can do:

```
where trunc(blabla) = trunc(sysdate) + 14
```

However, this can preclude the use of an index, because of the function.  One way around this is:

```
where blabla >= trunc(sysdate) + 14 and blabla < trunc(sysdate) + 15
```

Answer (score 1):

To be more standards compliant and avoid type conversions use CURRENT_DATE to get the date and INTERVAL to add a time interval to it.

```
SELECT blabla
FROM table
WHERE blabla = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '14' DAY
```